# Why does CefSharp shows errors on some websites

Tags: c#, browser, cefsharp

I build a small browser with cefsharp. When I go with my browser on https://www.kitanetz.de/bayern/86447/schulstr-29.php then I see the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKtUM.png

When I use for example firefox, I see the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/91GCq.png

Do someone have an idea why this happen?

Thank you and best Regards

Comment: No images of errors please. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: I used firefox and it takes me to the first one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try setting the UserAgent in your browser: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#useragent